# I imported `<Routing/>`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I imported `<Routing/>` to Main App, then the error `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` occurred.

My app is working without the  component, but I need fix this error.
Please help me.

```
const Routing = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    if (user) {
      dispatch({ type: "USER", payload: user });
    } else {
      if (!history.location.pathname.startsWith("/reset"))
        history.push("/signin");
    }
  }, []);

  return ();
};


function App() {
  return (
    <>
           ***<Routing />***
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You say you imported it, but you code shows a single function. If you did import it then the problem is likely with how you are doing your import or export. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Basic sample example [Live Demo CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-paper-v0wbp?file=/src/App.js):

```
const Routing = () => <h1>Hello from Routing</h1>;

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routing />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

Your full code with corrections:

```
const Routing = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    if (user) {
      dispatch({ type: "USER", payload: user });
    } else {
      if (!history.location.pathname.startsWith("/reset"))
        history.push("/signin");
    }
  }, []);
  return <></>;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routing />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -2):

I fixed. i imported useHistory from 'react'. it was mistake. Correct answer: useHistory from 'react-router-dom'